# using "add fetch request" in Xcodes UI

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, nsfetchrequest

It seems that there is a convenient way to use fetch controllers using the UI of xcdatamodel. I tried to use it but could not figure out how you actually implement the fetch once I have created it. anyone have some experience with this? A link? And most of all, is it possible to comfortably add this to a fetchResultsController?

[image]

Thanks!

EDIT: the answer here [core data simple fetch request template in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607085/core-data-simple-fetch-request-template-in-swift) helped me use the tool but I feel like it is not a full answer. (Thank you shallowThought)

Comment: Did you see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6430477/how-do-i-generate-code-or-find-the-code-generated-for-fetch-requests-i-created ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [core data simple fetch request template in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32607085/core-data-simple-fetch-request-template-in-swift)